# Problem with upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, upgrade, shutdown

I recently upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10. However during the upgrade, my laptop shutdown because I forgot to plug in the charger.

However after looking online I've managed to make it work and now the login screen shows 11.10 but when I login, I see no terminal in the launcher or any upgrade manager, plus there are no buttons on the right side at the top, only 1 which shows wifi strength, no apps and dash doesn't return results.

Please help. I have no CD available for live boot but have bootable USB with 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Looks like it's time for a re-install! Do you have any valuable data that you'd like to keep in your current Ubuntu installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have have to re - install it because Ubuntu might not have installed some important files which are causing you this problems. I would not recommend you to directly update but instead to download the iso, burn it, boot it, and install it.

First charge your laptop fully. Then boot from USB and install it.
I recommend you to read these articles :

> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation
>   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Comment: thats what i tried doing and hence i just got the 12.04lts iso and made it a bootable usb as mentioned on the website.what next?

Comment: no valuable data.recently switched to ubuntu and wiped windows

Comment: then creating a new partition table will be the best!